# SQL SELECT looking for a name like a substring in a join

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, t-sql

[image]

How should I solve this question?

[image]

My SQL statement is:

```
select ename 
from employee e 
    inner join certified c on e.eid = c.eid 
    inner join aircraft a on c.aid = a.aid 
    where cruisingrange> 1000 && a.aname not like'%b'
```

The answer I get with this query is *Jacob and Emily* which is wrong. Jacob should not be retrieved.

How should I modify or add to the SQL statement?

Script:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee (
    Eid int, 
    Ename nvarchar(100), 
    Salary int
)

INSERT INTO Employee VALUES
(1,'Jacob',85000),(2,'Michael',55000),(3,'Emily',80000),
(4,'Ashley',110000),(5,'Daniel',80000),(6,'Olivia',70000)

CREATE TABLE Aircraft (
    Aid int, 
    Aname nvarchar(100), 
    Cruisingrange int
)

INSERT INTO Aircraft VALUES
(1,'a1',800),(2,'a2b',700),(3,'a3',1000),
(4,'a4b',1100),(5,'a5',1200)

CREATE TABLE Flight (
    Flno int, 
    Fly_from nvarchar(100), 
    Fly_to nvarchar(100), 
    Distance int,
    Price int
)

INSERT INTO Flight VALUES
(1,'LA','SF',600,65000),(2,'LA','SF',700,70000),(3,'LA','SF',800,90000),
(4,'LA','NY',1000,85000),(5,'NY','LA',1100,95000)

CREATE TABLE Certified (
    Eid int, 
    Aid int, 
    CertDate date
)

INSERT INTO Certified VALUES
(1, 1, '2005-01-01'),(1, 2, '2001-01-01'),(1, 3, '2000-01-01'),
(1, 5, '2000-01-01'),(2, 3, '2002-01-01'),(2, 2, '2003-01-01'),
(3, 3, '2003-01-01'),(3, 5, '2004-01-01')
```

Comment: Links break. Add all necessary info directly into the question

Comment: Why this question is downvoted? It has one clear question, it has a query that OP tried to use, there was a lack of data sample but this was fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would read the "not certified on any" to be a check for the existence of a row.

If a matching row exists, then don't return the employee. Only return the emplouee if a matching row doesn't exist.

How would you find a matching row, to find out if an employee is "certified on any"?

There are several approaches. The two best approaches to use 1) anti-join and 2) NOT EXISTS (correlated subquery).

---

example **`NOT EXISTS (correlated subquery)`**

Of the two approaches this one is easier to see how it works.

```
  FROM e
 WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                      FROM certified c
                      JOIN aircraft a 
                        ON a.id = c.a_id
                     WHERE a.aname LIKE '%b%'   
                       AND c.e_id = e.id
                  )
```

Note the reference to the outer table (e.id) in the predicate of the subquery. The subquery is "correlated" with the outer query.

Think of if this way: for every row returned by the outer query, the subquery is executed, passing in the value of `e.id`. (The optimizer doesn't *have* to perform the operation this way; that's just an easy way of thinking about what we're asking for.)

If the subquery returns 1 or more rows, the condition EXISTS is satisfied, and returns TRUE. If the subquery returns zero rows, EXISTS evaluates to FALSE.

---

example of **anti-join pattern**

This approach can take a bit to get your brain wrapped around. Once you do "get it", it's an invaluable tool to keep handy in the SQL toolbelt.

If we use an OUTER JOIN, and pull back all rows from `e` along with any matching rows, then we can "exclude" the rows that found a match.

```
  FROM e
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT c.e_id
           FROM certified c
           JOIN aircraft a
             ON a.id = c.a_id
          WHERE a.aname LIKE '%b%'
         GROUP BY c.e_id
       ) b
    ON b.e_id = e.id
 WHERE b.e_id IS NULL
```

The inline view query is materialized into a derived table named `b`. That query is intended to return the id of every employee that is certified to fly any aircraft meeting the specified criteria. Then the rows in the derived table are outer joined to `e`.

The "trick" is the outer join (to include both rows with matches, and rows without matches, and the condition in the WHERE clause that excludes rows that had matches.

---

I expect someone else will provide an example of how to use a `NOT IN (subquery)`. With that approach, beware of what happens if the subquery returns any NULL values. (HINT: you will want to ensure that the subquery will never ever return a NULL.)

This demonstrates only two of several possible approaches to satisfying the "is not certified on any" criteria.

Obviously, additional joins/subqueries will need to be added to evaluate the other criteria in the query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query in **SQL Server** (maybe it will work on MySQL too):

```
SELECT e.Ename
FROM Employee e 
INNER JOIN Certified c 
    ON e.Eid = c.Eid 
LEFT JOIN aircraft a 
    ON c.Aid = a.Aid and a.Cruisingrange> 1000
LEFT JOIN aircraft a1 
    ON c.Aid = a1.Aid and a1.aname like'%b%'
GROUP BY e.Ename
HAVING MAX(a.Aid) IS NOT NULL AND MAX(a1.Aid) IS NULL
```

We join all tables we need with conditions we need. Then we group by `Ename` and use `MAX(a.Aid) IS NOT NULL` that means that pilot can operate an air-vehicle with `Cruisingrange > 1000` and `MAX(a1.Aid) IS NULL` means he is not certified on any aircraft with `b` in name.